# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation Ubuntu Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I am using `Laravel` web framework on my `ubuntu 14.04` server and `Nginx` web server, I have this error when I try to upload a file using `Laravel` to the server.
my upload directory is on the `public/uploads` folder that has 777 permission.

Comment: I want to comment on this because I see the question is popular now,
Never use 777 permission :)
In my case, it was a test to check why it was not writing the file.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The GD Graphics Library is for dynamically manipulating images.
For Ubuntu you should install it manually:

- PHP8.0: `sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd`
- PHP8.1: `sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd`
- PHP8.2: `sudo apt-get install php8.2-gd`
- PHP8.3: `sudo apt-get install php8.3-gd`

That's all, you can verify that GD support loaded:

```
php -i | grep -i gd
```

Output should be like this:

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.1.1-dev
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

and finally restart your apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd  for PHP 5.6 version

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd

Comment: ...and don't forget to reload apache2 afterwards e.g. service apache2 reload

Comment: If you're using apache server, after installing, reload `sudo systemctl restart apache2`  

Then go back and reload your page and upload a new doc. It should work

Comment: If you're using php's internal server (php artisan serve for the artisans), make sure you stop the server and restart it. Restarting/reloading apache won't help.

Comment: if above command not works. Use "yum search gd" you will see output as php72-gd.x86_64, php71-gd.x86_64, php73-gd.x86_64 etc. Then Use command "sudo yum install php72-gd.x86_64" it works for me.

Comment: also don't forget to restart laravel development server if you are using laravel.

Comment: I'm using nginx. It wasn't needed to restart the service after installing the extension.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php8.1-gd

Answer (score 33):

**window users** using xampp apache server.

Go to php folder in xampp and open the php.ini and php configurations settings file, and
change the line ;extension=gd2 or the line ;extension=gd to just extension=gd2

**NB**  that php version 8 is stored as ;extension=gd

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama I bet you hate multi-purpose things.

Comment: @akinuri sure he does, this answer actually helped me!

Answer (score 20):

For my fellow Windows users, find the line `;extension=gd2` in your `php.ini` file and change it to `extension=gd2`.

Regards

Comment: for PHP 8, the line would be extension=gd and not extension=gd2

Comment: may be extension=gd2 OR extension=gd ony one of them (100% Workes fo me)

Answer (score 15):

@limonte's answer is correct, but if you're using PHP7+, you should use following command:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

If you don't know what version of PHP you're using, just type

`php -v`

Output should start with something similar to `PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )`.

Answer (score 9):

for php -v 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

works for me

Answer (score 8):

Php 5.6 worked with below command

PHP5.6: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd`

after installing restart server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 7):

Go to your xampp serve:

[image]

After that, you just click on the Apache config button and you get an option on `PHP(php.ini)`. Click this option and then it will be open on code editor.

After that, you will search a file `gd` and you get `;extension=gd` this option. Remove the`;` from `extension=gd` and then save it.

Then restart your server again, then it will be work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's mostly a duplicate of @Arinzehills's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66848711/7451109)

Answer (score 3):

In my case under Archlinux:

```
pacman -S php-gd
```

[php-gd](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/php-gd/)

then in your `php.ini` for me in `/etc/php/php.ini` uncomment line `;extension=gd.so` by removing semicolon.

Don't forget to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xampp PHP Version 8.* , on xampp control panel, click on config under apache and select `PHP(php.ini)` , this will open php.ini config file. Search for `;extension=gd` and Change it to  `extension=gd` . It is not a must you follow this process to get to php.ini, the most important thing is that you have to change  `;extension=gd` to `extension=gd` on php.ini config file. Restart Xampp and that is it!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Wnmp PHP version 8.*, on Wnmp look for php.ini located at C:\Wnmp\php. Remove the comment `;extension=gd` to `extension=gd`

Then restart the Nginx on Wnmp

Answer (score -1):

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        .....
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your XAMPP and click on Config. Open php.ini
After that, find ;extension=gd and remove the semicolon and its works.

Answer (score -1):

For windows users

1. Go to php.ini file located in C:/xampp/php
2. Where the file type is written as "configuration settings"
   Once u doubleclick and it opens, search for gd. You will get something like this
   ;extension=gd
3. Uncomment it by taking out that semicolon at the beginning then save the file and close it.
   Then go to this path c:/xampp/php/ext
   Copy this file
   php_gd.dll
   To c:/windows/system32
4. Paste it there. Now restart ur xampp server. It'll work. Simple as that.
   Sorry for the long episodes ☺️☺️