# Laravel 5.7 on Ubuntu "GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.''

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, gd, gdlib

I'm trying to upload images using dropzone but I get this error

```
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation
```

PHP version is 7.2.10 on Ubuntu 18 so I tried to install the gd library after finding this answer [Stackoverflow answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009844/gd-library-extension-not-available-with-this-php-installation-ubuntu-nginx/39181438#answer-34010095) so I executed

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
php -i | grep -i gd
```

And the result is

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.2.5
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
GDMSESSION => ubuntu
XAUTHORITY => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
$_SERVER['GDMSESSION'] => ubuntu
$_SERVER['XAUTHORITY'] => /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
```

**I restarted Apache and tried to upload again but I still get the same error and that answer didn't work for me**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation Ubuntu Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009844/gd-library-extension-not-available-with-this-php-installation-ubuntu-nginx)

Comment: Actually, it won't work because OP is serving their laravel app from php's internal server as opposed to apache. One has to stop the PHP internal server and start it again for newly installed extensions to be loaded in. See my answer for more details. @SandOfVega

Answer (score 2):

If serving your app from `php artisan serve` please note the following:

Even after restarting your apache server it won't matter because you are still running php's internal server.

You have to stop `php artisan serve` and start it again for the new extensions you've installed to be loaded.

If you don't do this, the php server will still be using the old settings that don't know about newly installed GD Library.

Edit:

Also, run `PHPinfo()` to find out which php.ini file you;re working with. Search for the line that says: `Loaded Configuration File`

Answer (score 1):

Changing Laravel port

```
php artisan serve --port=ANY_OTHER_PORT
```

Then restarted Apache that worked for me