# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation. Laravel 9 Error

Tags: php, laravel, gd, laravel-9

I work with Laravel 9 and when I want to use `Image::make($image)->save('upload/home'.$name_gen);` which I added earlier, I am getting the error:

> GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.

`extension=gd` is enabled in `php.ini`, but when I go to the console and I write `php -m`, `gd` does not appear there.

I tried reinstalling `php` and `xampp`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right PHP INI file? Try running `PHP --ini` to see which INI file is being used.

Comment: thank you, it helped, but I don't understand why it pulls data from the random php file that is in my downloads dir, how can I change it so that it takes data from xampp php.ini?

Comment: There's probably a place in XAMPP where you may tell it what INI file to use. Never used XAMPP so I can't be more of a help in that regard I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation Ubuntu Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009844/gd-library-extension-not-available-with-this-php-installation-ubuntu-nginx)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the bad php folder and setting the path to the new php folder in Windows Environment Variables. The problem was that Windows found the wrong path to Php